# Does .Net core 2.0 support WCF discovery

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core, service-discovery

I have an IoT device running .net core 2.0 and it needs to find a WCF service running in the local network. Does .net core support WCF service discovery and if yes how do I import it properly?

Comment: Ask the developers, https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this question correctly, I believe that you can add a reference using the tool and methods described in [this link from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide).